# Accessing Array in Assembler

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16, dosbox

I'm having a problem while programming in assembler. I'm making the game "4 in a row" in assembler and already managed to write the code to draw the playing field of 7x6. 
I'm using a array to keep track of the playing field and use a array with the different collor codes.

```
  PlayingField DB 42 DUP(0)   ;0 for empty, 1 for yellow, 2 for res
  CollorList DB 1111b, 1110b, 0100b (white, yellow, res)
  CurrentBlock DB 0
```

To draw my playing field I use the following code.

```
  mov al, CollorList[2]    ;collor register
  mov ch, 000000
  mov dh, 000000
  mov cl, Position[0]
  mov dl, Position[1]
  mov ah, 0ch
  int 10h                   ;set pixel
```

The problem I now have it to use the variable CurrentBlock as a index like this PlayingField[CurrentBlock]. This value I need to store so I can use it in the drawing section of the code as the index of the CollorList. Like this CollorList[index].
This way value I then need to put into the al register so I get a white pixel for the value 0 of the currentblock, yellow for value 1 and red for value 2.

Also I should like to now how I change the value an certain index in my PlayingField array. Because " mov PlayingField[currentblock], 2 doesn't seem to work.

Assembler is new to me and searched online but didn't find my answer yet. Any help I greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Tim

Edit:
Im using DOS + MASM/LINK. Will try it if it works this way. I tryed something like this but doesn't seem to work.

```
mov si,2    
mov bx, [PlayingField+si] 
mov al, CollorList[dx]
```

This gives me an error because [PlayingField+si] is 8bit and bx 16bit. If I change my register to an 'bl' it complains in the last line of the code because 'bl' is a 8bit register

Comment: Shouldn't the last line read `mov al, CollorList[bx]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using NASM, you can change `mov PlayingField[currentblock], 2` into:

```
mov si, [currentblock]
mov byte [playingfield+si], 2
```

Comment: Im using DOS + MASM/LINK
Will try it if it works this way.

I tryed something like this but doesn't seem to work.
  <pre> mov si,2
    mov bx, [PlayingField+si] 
    mov al, CollorList[dx] `
  <code>
This gives me an error because [PlayingField+si] is 8bit and bx 16bit. If I change my register to an 'bl' it complains in the last line of the code because it is a 16bit

Comment: try `mov bl, byte ptr [PlayingField+si]` instead of `mov bx, [PlayingField+si]`

Comment: Worked it out. Used the register ax and filled ah with 00000 and al with my number. Then moved ax into si so I didn't got the 16bit error. Thx for your help